# Sending a notification to a server on page reload

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get my html embedded javascript to send a notification to my python flask server, if the user leaves/refreshes the page, or just before I call location.reload().

I have an onbeforeunload event handler, but it does not seem to trigger in any of the refresh cases.

Is there any way to send said notification to the server (a json file in this case) in the case of refresh?

Why doesn't the line before location.reload() seem to trigger?

I use fetch for sending the request, in case of closing the tab everything works fine.

Tested in Firefox v102.15.1.

I used the event handler as such:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
            send_msg();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The beforeunload event handler is not triggered on page refresh by default. This is because refreshing the page is considered a normal navigation event, and the beforeunload event is only triggered when the user is leaving the page.

To send a notification to the server on page refresh, you can use a combination of the beforeunload event handler and the location.reload() method. The following code will send a JSON file to the server before the page is refreshed:

JavaScript

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
  // Send the JSON file to the server
  fetch('/server/endpoint', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      // Your data here
    })
  });

  // Refresh the page
  location.reload();
});
```

Kodu kullanırken dikkatli olun. Daha fazla bilgi
The beforeunload event handler will be triggered before the location.reload() method is called, so the JSON file will be sent to the server before the page is refreshed.

One thing to note is that the beforeunload event handler may not be triggered in all cases. For example, if the user presses the Ctrl+F5 keys to force a refresh, the beforeunload event handler will not be triggered.

Here are some possible reasons why your beforeunload event handler is not triggering on page refresh:

You are using an old version of a browser. The beforeunload event handler was not supported in all browsers until recently.
You are using a browser extension that is blocking the beforeunload event handler.
You are refreshing the page using a method that does not trigger the beforeunload event handler, such as pressing the Ctrl+F5 keys.
If you are sure that your beforeunload event handler is properly configured, but it is still not triggering on page refresh, you can try debugging the issue using the browser's developer tools.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately the location.reload() has it's own trigger condition. It mostly triggers when the page is notified of a change on client side, thus I can't put it in the event listener.